# Build in a directory other than 'src' with scons does not copy deps to variant_dir

Tags: d, scons

I'm trying to use scons for my project.  I have the following so far:

SConstruct

```
path = ['/usr/local/bin', '/usr/bin', '/bin']
libpath = ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/lib']
env = Environment()
env.Append(ENV = {'PATH' : path})
env.Append(DFLAGS = ['-version=placeholder', '-g'])
env.Append(LIBPATH = libpath)
env.Append(DPATH = '#/build_debug/')
Export('env')
env.SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir = 'build_debug',
               exports = {'DFLAGS' : '-debug'})
```

src/SConscript

```
Import('env')
env.Program(target = 'a.out',
            source = ['stubs.d'] + Glob('*/*.d'))
```

When trying to build, though, it gives:

```
build_debug/foo/foo.d:9: Error: module bar is in file 'bar/bar.d' which cannot be read
```

Checking `ls build_debug` shows that not all the files have been copied over.

I think that I had this working earlier; but I must've messed something up since then.

EDIT:
All my source code sits in project/src/ and I would like for the build to happen in project/build/; my SConstruct file sits in project/.

Answer (score 1):

Out of source builds are not supported by SCons, so dont be surprised by unexpected behavior.

They are talking about adding this feature on the SCons dev email lists soon, but they havent said when.

Ive noticed a few things that could be improved in your scripts:

In the call to SConscript() in the SConstruct, the exports is the DFLAGS variable, but in the SConscript, you are only importing the 'env', so the DFLAGS variable wont be visible. You should either import the DFLAGS, or just set the DFLAGS in the env as a different variable, and just get it from the env in the SConscript.

Also, Im not sure the library paths will work correctly as is. You have this:

```
libpath = ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/lib']
env.Append(LINKFLAGS = libpath)
```

But as is, SCons wont prepend the `-L` to each libpath. Instead of using `LINKFLAGS` use `LIBPATH`, then SCons will prepend the `-L`.

Comment: But I was under the impression that the point of variant_dir was to build it in a directory other than the source tree?  And thanks for the LIBPATH thing.

Comment: @Infiltrator, sounds like we need to clarify this. SCons only supports building source code that is in the same subdirectory structure as the root SConstruct, likewise with the location of the variant_dir. Typically out of source refers to specifying the variant_dir as a directory ***not*** under the SConstruct. Which are you trying to do?

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken in my terminology, then; I shall update the question to clarify.

Comment: "Out of source builds are not supported by SCons". I don't understand. Isn't variant_dir supposed to make an out-of-source build work?

Comment: Isn't the build directory of the questioner below SConstruct?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set `duplicate` parameter to `0`

```
env.SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir = 'build_debug',
               exports = {'DFLAGS' : '-debug'}, duplicate=0)
```

Comment: My problem is that it's _not_ copying things over.  :)  Thanks anyway.